# Transparent proxying for all docker containers

Tags: proxy, docker, iptables

I'm running docker containers from behind a firewall and it is always problematic that I have to set the proxying parameters in each container. This is especially bad when I run builds from `Dockerfile`s.

I have redsocks set up so that it proxies outgoing traffic from my host automatically but docker containers seem to not go through this chain.

```
user@user ~ $ sudo iptables -L -t nat -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDSOCKS_FILTER  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDSOCKS_FILTER  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.4           172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:5050

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain REDSOCKS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 12347
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 12346
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp redir ports 12345

Chain REDSOCKS_FILTER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/8         
.....
REDSOCKS   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Is there any way to get packets originating from containers to go through the same REDSOCKS_FILTER as everything else does on my machine.

Comment: What is your container management system? As in: Kubernetes, Mesos+Marathon, Nomad, or maybe a homegrown one?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas No mgmt, it's just my linux host

Comment: @michael-hausenblas It seems like the proxying actually works. The issue is that DNS goes through UDP and redsocks proxies only TCP at the moment. But I feel like I'm closing in on some conclusion.